# It was my first time

Tags: sentence-construction

> It was my first time to watch a movie.

> It is my first time to watch movie.

> It is my first time watching movie.

> This is my first time cooking pasta.

Are these sentences correct??

Comment: *It was my first time **of watching** a movie.* But  the preposition can [just about] be discarded, so your #4 *This is my first time cooking pasta* does in fact occur with native speakers (but note you'll encounter ***at*** there as well as ***of*** or "no preposition"). Long and short of it - there is no standard preposition in English for linking *[first] **time*** to a gerund / present participle denoting an activity. Different people have different ideas, and many of us would simply rephrase to avoid having to make a choice - *This is the first time [that] **I have cooked pasta***.

Answer (score 1):

The first two are not idiomatic.

The third and fourth are both possible, provided you add the missing *a* in the third: I cannot think of any context or construction in which "watching movie" would be grammatical.

But more natural still would be

> It's the first time I've watched a movie.

> This is the first time I've cooked pasta.

There is no rule or logic about this: it's just the way we happen to say it.

*Time* meaning "occasion" happens to take a "that" clause (my examples use "that" clauses, even though the "that" can be omitted) or an *-ing* clause, but not a "to" infinitive clause.

On the other hand, *time* meaning "point in time" does take a "to" clause (eg "It's time to get up now") and not an "-ing" clause

Comment: I think Colin just missed the lack of an article there - *my first time watching **a** movie*.

Comment: I beg your pardon, I saw the lack of article in the second, but missed it in the third. Now added that to my answer

Answer (score 0):

> 1. It was my first time to watch a movie.
> 2. It is my first time to watch movie.
> 3. It is my first time watching movie.
> 4. This is my first time cooking pasta.

Only the last sentence (4) is correct. The first three are incorrect.

In all of those sentences, the proper form of the second verb (the verb indicating what you *are* or *were* do**ing**) is the present participle: "verb+ing." So the (3) and (4) have the correct form; (1) and (2) do not.

Then you have noun-article agreement. "Movie" is a **count noun** and takes an article, whether indefinite (**a** movie) or definite (**the** movie). So (1) has the correct agreement while (2) and (3) do not. "Pasta" is a **mass noun** (uncountable); you might say "some pasta" but not "a pasta," so sentence (4) is correct.

So: For the first test, sentences (3) and (4) pass; for the second test sentences (1) and (4) pass. Sentence (4) is the only one that passes both and is correct.

Comment: So it is correct to say, " it was my first time watching a movie?

Comment: @EraserHead yes, that is a perfectly fine sentence.